# Is there a before/after edit view in OS X Photos' Editing view?

Tags: photos

I've used photo editing apps before that show a before/after split view, so you can see the original image and the edited image either side by side or overlaid. Like this:

[image: Comparison view]

Is there a similar editing view in OS X Photos?